# Strange bug with function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I'm trying to use a script on my website who pop a navbar. There is a declaration on this script :

```
(function($){
$.cookieBar = function(options,val){
   ....
};
   some other stuff here
})(jQuery);
```

We can see this script [here](http://www.primebox.co.uk/projects/cookie-bar/) it's working without any problem on all of my website called with :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.cookieBar();
});
```

In just one webpage there is a bug (css and js are include) :

> TypeError: $.cookieBar is not a function
>
> $.cookieBar();

I don't understand why. If anyone have any idea. On this webpage there is one major script who is working normaly without this cookie-nav-script but because of this bug nothing work at all.
I don't use any experimental stuff from this script and I attached this cookies-bar at the body.

Comment: You need to provide the rest of the page code for the page that does not work. A single typo, or failure to include the first piece of code, will cause subsequent code to fail.

Comment: If there's an error in JS, any further JS won't run. Figure out why you get `$.cookieBar is not a function` and the rest will work.

Comment: On chrome i have found this :
 style: function( elem, name, value, extra ) {
  // Don't set styles on text and comment nodes
  if ( !elem || elem.nodeType === 3 || elem.nodeType === 8 || !elem.style ) {
   return;
  }
Who normaly help me but .. I just don't understand.

Comment: Are *both* of these code blocks placed before you load jQuery or after? They need to both be after.

Comment: Are *both* of your code blocks place. after you load jQuery. Make sure they are.